# Add values to a tree

Tags: c, binary-search-tree, addition

I'm trying to add values to a binary search tree so for that I've written two functions one that create a new node and another which insert these values to the tree
So this is the code

```
typedef struct Node {

    void *data;
    struct Node *left;
    struct Node *right;
} Node;

 Node *createNode(void *data,size_t s){

    Node *newNode = (Node *)malloc(s * sizeof(Node));
    newNode->data = data;
    newNode->left = NULL;
    newNode->right = NULL;

    return newNode;
}


void addValueBt(Node ** node, void *data, size_t s,int (* compar)(const void *, const void *)){

    if (*node == NULL)
      *node = createNode(data,s);
    else if (compar((*node)->data,data) > 0)
                 addValueBt(&(*node)->left, data, s, compar);
    else
        addValueBt(&(*node)->right, data, s, compar);
}
```

When I call addValueBt in the main with two different ways (but normally seems to be the same thing) I don't get the same result

1st way:

```
int main(){

    Node *root = NULL;
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        addValueBt(&root, &i, 1, myCompar);
    printBt(root,print);//print the whole tree
}
```

The display gives this:

```
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
```

2nd way:

```
int main(){

 int a = 8, b = 9, c = 5, d = 1;
 addValueBt(&root, &a, 1, myCompar);  
 addValueBt(&root, &b, 1, myCompar);
 addValueBt(&root, &c, 1, myCompar);
 addValueBt(&root, &d, 1, myCompar);
 printBt(root,print);

}
```

The display:

```
1
5
8
9
```

"myCompar" compares between two integers

My question is: why it doesn't work when we use the function 'addValueBt' in the loop ?
(normally it should give the same result as for the other one )

Comment: You're passing the ***address*** of `i`, not the value of `i`. So all of the nodes point to the same data.

Comment: This is tangential to your main problem, but the parameter `s` is initially confusing.  It's always `1` because you only allocate one node at a time.  If it was larger, you'd waste the extra space that `createNode()` does allocate but does not initialize.  You could stop using `s` (assume `1`) without causing problems in the visible code.

Comment: @user3386109 : yeah the adress of 'i' doesn't change but its content  normally change with the different values

Comment: @JonathanLeffler : what do you mean  by that and what do you suggest to me to do Do you mean that I have to change the value of s or it depends of the value  I add cause I add only one node at once

Comment: I mean that in `Node *createNode(void *data, size_t s) { Node *newNode = (Node *)malloc(s * sizeof(Node));`, you allocate an array of `Node` structures of the size given by `s`.  However, you initialize only the first structure allocated, and you don't record the size of the array anywhere.  This doesn't matter because if you track the calls from `main()` to `addValueBt()` to `createNode()`, the value of `s` is always `1`.  But because it is always `1`, you really have no need to pass it, so you can simplify the calls all the way down the calling chain.

Comment: Note that @user3386109: has identified the problem.  You store the same pointer in each element of the tree, so when the pointed at value changes, all the elements of the tree change at the same time.  And if the pointed at value goes out of scope, you get undefined behaviour.  You either need to make a copy of the data in the `createNode()` function, which means that you need to know how big the data is so that you can allocate new space to store it, or you need to ensure that a different pointer is passed to the code each time, and those pointers remain valid until the tree is freed.

Comment: You can see with your working code, you pass a different pointer each time (a pointer to a different variable).  When you repeatedly pass a pointer to the same variable, the same address is stored, so the current value stored at that address is used by all the nodes; they all have the same value.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I understood your explanation (thank you for that) but when you say that I have to make a copy of the data you mean that I have to do like this                                                                               Node *createNode(void *key,size_t s)
{                                                                                                              void *data = key;
    Node *newNode = (Node *)malloc(s * sizeof(Node));
    newNode->key = data;
    newNode->left = NULL;
    newNode->right = NULL;

    return newNode;
} I think i'm wrong by doing this

Comment: Uurrgghhh!  Part of the problem comes from using `void *data;` instead of a simple `int data;`.  For the immediate purposes, life would be much, much simpler if your data structure used `int data;`.  You'd have `Node *createNode(int key) { Node *newNode = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node)); newNode->data = data; newNode->left = NULL; newNode->right = NULL; return newNode; }`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler yeah I know but I have to do that so that it  can be used with other types like float or char

Comment: If you store `void *`, you really need to know how long the data you're storing pointers to is, so that you can make copies, etc.  Your comparator can make assumptions about the length (and you'll be OK as long as those assumptions are correct).  So, you'd need `Node *createNode(void *data, size_t len) { void *copy = malloc(len); memmove(copy, data, len); Node *newNode = (Node *)malloc(s * sizeof(Node)); newNode->data = copy; newNode->left = NULL; newNode->right = NULL; return newNode; }`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler another question I used what you suggested me to do and when i used it in the main by doing this    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
     
     insert(&root, &i, sizeof i, myCompar);     it displays from 0 to 9 twice

Comment: @JonathanLefflerPart of the problem is resolved just the fact that is like repeated twice that disturbs me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Primary problem

As [user3386109](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3386109/user3386109) correctly pointed out in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47370114/add-values-to-a-tree/47370871#comment81692924_47370114), the primary problem is that you're storing a pointer to the data in your tree, not a copy of the data.  All the nodes end up pointing at the same location, so when that location changes, the value pointed at by the tree changes in all nodes at once.

#### Secondary issues

In a collection of comments (some of them responses to comment questions by [Yasmine](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7698859/yasmine), the OP), I noted:

> This is tangential to your main problem, but the parameter `s` is initially confusing. It's always 1 because you only allocate one node at a time. If it was larger, you'd waste the extra space that `createNode()` does allocate but does not initialize. You could stop using `s` (assume 1) without causing problems in the visible code.
>
> I mean that in `Node *createNode(void *data, size_t s) { Node *newNode = (Node *)malloc(s * sizeof(Node));`, you allocate an array of `Node` structures of the size given by `s`. However, you initialize only the first structure allocated, and you don't record the size of the array anywhere. This doesn't matter because if you track the calls from `main()` to `addValueBt()` to `createNode()`, the value of `s` is always `1`. But because it is always 1, you really have no need to pass it, so you can simplify the calls all the way down the calling chain.
>
> Note that @user3386109: has identified the problem. You store the same pointer in each element of the tree, so when the pointed at value changes, all the elements of the tree change at the same time. And if the pointed at value goes out of scope, you get undefined behaviour. You either need to make a copy of the data in the `createNode()` function, which means that you need to know how big the data is so that you can allocate new space to store it, or you need to ensure that a different pointer is passed to the code each time, and those pointers remain valid until the tree is freed.
>
> You can see with your working code, you pass a different pointer each time (a pointer to a different variable). When you repeatedly pass a pointer to the same variable, the same address is stored, so the current value stored at that address is used by all the nodes; they all have the same value.
>
> Part of the problem comes from using `void *data;` instead of a simple `int data;`. For the immediate purposes, life would be much, much simpler if your data structure used `int data;`. You'd have:
>
> ```
> Node *createNode(int key)
> {
>     Node *newNode = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
>     newNode->data = data; newNode->left = NULL;
>     newNode->right = NULL;
>     return newNode;
> }
> ```
>
> If you store `void *`, you really need to know how long the data you're storing pointers to is, so that you can make copies, etc. Your comparator can make assumptions about the length (and you'll be OK as long as those assumptions are correct). So, you'd need:
>
> ```
> Node *createNode(void *data, size_t len)
> {
>     void *copy = malloc(len);
>     memmove(copy, data, len);
>     Node *newNode = (Node *)malloc(s * sizeof(Node));
>     newNode->data = copy;
>     newNode->left = NULL;
>     newNode->right = NULL;
>     return newNode;
> }
> ```

Yasmine commented:

> **I know but I have to do that so that it can be used with other types like `float` or `char`**.

At that point, I started to produce the code below.

#### Working code

Here's an offering dealing with the points made in my comments.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

typedef struct Node
{
    void *data;
    size_t datalen;
    struct Node *left;
    struct Node *right;
} Node;

static int cmp_dbl(const void *p1, const void *p2);
static int cmp_int(const void *p1, const void *p2);
static void freeBt(Node *node);
static void printBt(Node *node, void (*print)(const void *));
static void print_dbl(const void *p);
static void print_int(const void *p);

extern Node *createNode(void *data, size_t len);
extern void addValueBt(Node **node, void *data, size_t len, int (*compar)(const void *, const void *));

Node *createNode(void *data, size_t len)
{
    void *copy = malloc(len);
    // Error check allocation!
    memmove(copy, data, len);
    Node *newNode = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(*newNode));
    // Error check allocation!
    newNode->data = copy;
    newNode->left = NULL;
    newNode->right = NULL;
    newNode->datalen = len;
    return newNode;
}

void addValueBt(Node **node, void *data, size_t len, int (*compar)(const void *, const void *))
{
    if (*node == NULL)
        *node = createNode(data, len);
    else if (compar((*node)->data, data) > 0)
        addValueBt(&(*node)->left, data, len, compar);
    else
        addValueBt(&(*node)->right, data, len, compar);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    unsigned seed = time(0);
    if (argc == 2)
        seed = atoi(argv[1]);
    srand(seed);
    printf("Seed: %u\n", seed);

    Node *root = NULL;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        addValueBt(&root, &i, sizeof(i), cmp_int);
    printBt(root, print_int);
    freeBt(root);

    root = NULL;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        double d = (double)rand() / RAND_MAX * 1000.0 + (double)rand() / RAND_MAX;
        addValueBt(&root, &d, sizeof(d), cmp_dbl);
    }
    printBt(root, print_dbl);
    freeBt(root);

    return 0;
}

static int cmp_int(const void *p1, const void *p2)
{
    int v1 = *(int *)p1;
    int v2 = *(int *)p2;
    return (v1 > v2) - (v1 < v2);
}

static int cmp_dbl(const void *p1, const void *p2)
{
    double v1 = *(double *)p1;
    double v2 = *(double *)p2;
    return (v1 > v2) - (v1 < v2);
}

static void print_int(const void *p)
{
    printf("%d\n", *(int *)p);
}

static void print_dbl(const void *p)
{
    printf("%8.3f\n", *(double *)p);
}

static void printBt(Node *node, void (*print)(const void *))
{
    if (node != 0)
    {
        printBt(node->left, print);
        print(node->data);
        printBt(node->right, print);
    }
}

static void freeBt(Node *node)
{
    if (node != 0)
    {
        freeBt(node->left);
        freeBt(node->right);
        free(node);
    }
}
```

Here's an example run:

```
Seed: 1511037421
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
  87.907
 118.694
 140.163
 170.833
 343.940
 412.792
 422.254
 530.731
 557.656
 936.981
```

#### What changed?

I dropped the parameter `s` to `addValueBt()` and `createNode()`, but added a parameter `size_t len`.  That defines the length of the data.  The length is stored in `size_t datalen` in the `Node` structure.

The code in `createNode()` makes a copy of the data it is passed and stores that copy in the tree.  This ensures that each node is unaffected by changes to the values in the calling code.

#### What was added?

I added code for the `int` comparator (you called yours `myCompar()`; I called mine `cmp_int()` because I also wanted to work with `double`), and a `double` comparator `cmp_dbl()`.  I added printing functions `print_int()` and `printf_dbl()` — renaming your `print` to `print_int`.  I added memory release function `freeBt()`.  I added code for `printBt()`.

The code playing with the command line arguments allows you to specify a seed of your choosing.  It's a bit sloppy; I should probably be using `strtoul()` instead of `atoi()`.  But it allows you to specify a number on the command line to be used as the seed, which will give you repeatability when you need it.  The seed is reported so you can reproduce results.  This is helpful when playing with random numbers — sometimes you want randomness, and sometimes you want repeatability.

#### What I didn't do

I didn't fix the printing code so that the structure of the tree is visible.  You just get a list of numbers.

The code doesn't really use the `datalen` member of the structure, but
it could be useful to check consistency, or for recording the length of strings.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help !! I learnt many things so thank you for that!!